# Calculating the center of a circle touching two points

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the centre of a circle touching two points given the points **p1**, **p2**, and a **radius**, I'm using an isosceles triangle's circumcircle to represent it. This operation would yield two points, one above the plane intersecting **p1** and **p2** and one below it, which is represented by a boolean argument.

This is how far I've gotten. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
auto getSection = [](const point & p1, const point & p2, double radius, bool dir) -> point
{
  static constexpr double sin90 = sin(90 * M_PI / 180.0);
  static constexpr double cos90 = cos(90 * M_PI / 180.0);
  static constexpr double sin270 = sin(270 * M_PI / 180.0);
  static constexpr double cos270 = cos(270 * M_PI / 180.0);
  point p3 = point((p2.x() - p1.x()) / 2, (p2.y() - p1.y()) / 2);
  double ang = std::atan2(p3.y(), p3.x());
  if (dir)
    return point(p3.x() + (cos90 + ang) * radius, p3.y() + (sin90 + ang) * radius);
  else
    return point(p3.x() + (cos270 + ang) * radius, p3.y() + (sin270 + ang) * radius);
};
```

Comment: there are two possible centers for a circle with just the described information

Comment: Yes. It's supposed to find either via the boolean argument.

Comment: i guess i should pay more attention :)

Comment: Why is there `cos90 + ang` in your formula, in which a value whose unit is radian is added to a cosine value?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I tried a couple of things and that was one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use any trigonometry... Start by calculating the midpoint and a vector from one of the points to the midpoint:

```
double midX = (p1.x() + p2.x()) / 2;
double midY = (p1.y() + p2.y()) / 2;
double dx = (p1.x() - p2.x()) / 2;
double dy = (p1.y() - p2.y()) / 2;
```

Then, calculate the distance from each point to the midpoint:

```
double dist = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

We can then calculate the distance from the midpoint to the center of the circle using the Pythagorean theorem:

```
double pDist = std::sqrt(radius * radius - dist * dist);
```

We can use all this information to calculate the vector from the midpoint to the center of the circle:

```
if(dir) {
    mDx = dy * pDist / dist;
    mDy = -dx * pDist / dist;
} else {
    mDx = -dy * pDist / dist;
    mDy = dx * pDist / dist;
}
```

Now, we can just add that vector to the midpoint, and return:

```
return point(midX + mDx, midY + mDy);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious problem is that you are using your `p3` as some sort of origin point from which you intend to measure your circle centers. Apparently the intent was to use the mid-point of `p1 -> p2` segment. But `p3` is calculated as `(p2 - p1) / 2`, while the mid-point of `p1 -> p2` segment is actually `(p1 + p2) / 2`. See the difference?

If you interpret `p3` as a point, then using it as an origin does not make any sense. `p3` is actually a vector, whose direction coincides with `p1 -> p2` segment and whose magnitude is half of `p1 -> p2` distance. So, if you are looking for the center of `p1 -> p2` segment, then it would be `p1 + p3`. Not just `p3`, but `p1 + p3`.

The second obvious problem is that you are for some reason adding the angle `ang` value to the cosine and sine values and then immediately use the result again as cosine and sine. That makes no sense at all.